# How to change strategy in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to change GPU used for training and evaluation for Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API.

I tried to change strategy for both eval and train. For eval I only need to use 1 GPU

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0"])
```

but 2 for train

I am getting this error:

> "RuntimeError: Mixing different tf.distribute.Strategy objects:
> <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategy
> object at

any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Chaine , Would like some more code to resolve the issue but Can you  `try the same declaring strategy only once  like  "mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])"` as when  you declare and use two distribute objects it raises run time error.  Exception is mentioned here in this link  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/105dbc2326e4fb36a793569e9834efe62e150d8d/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribution_strategy_context.py#L308

Comment: Hi @TensorflowSupport thanks for your reply. I need to use 2 strategy objects because evaluation using 2 GPUs is not possible (or is it?) hence i need to change device during evaluation

Comment: Yes ,using Two GPU's is possible , Can you please check the above command and confirm. Context of distribute strategy to distributing computation between multiple GPU's